# Questions relating to Sonic 3 and Sonic & Knuckles can also relate to the combined game - should we add this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sonic 3 and Sonic & Knuckles were first released on cartridges for the Sega Genesis/ Mega Drive. These cartridges can be physically joined to access the combined game, Sonic 3 & Knuckles. As such, most questions relating to [sonic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-3) & [sonic-and-knuckles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-and-knuckles) will also relate to the combined game.

I'm ok with the separate games existing as separate tags, however all the current questions under these tags (all 3 of them) also relate to the combined game [sonic-3-and-knuckles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-3-and-knuckles).

Should we add [sonic-3-and-knuckles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-3-and-knuckles) to the questions in the other two tags, as they all relate to their single game and the combined game? If more questions are asked in future, we can then add this tag to those questions as the situation warrants.

Comment: What are you up to Robotnik!?!?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - My badniks need a combined home :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I see minimal benefit to the combined tags - I can't imagine there's any significant subset of people who are interested only in the combined games, and I don't expect anyone to not search for [sonic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-3) if they're really looking for questions about [sonic-3-and-knuckles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-3-and-knuckles). I can't think of any real reasons to discourage it though. If you'd like to add it for the existing questions for which it's applicable, go for it.

Comment: Sonic 3 & Knuckles was the best; I wouldn't play the others again, and I've gotten the impression I'm not alone.  However I see no need for the combined tags, either.

Comment: @DaveMcCelland As someone who has played the games to death, I can tell you that Sonic 3 & Knuckles combined is more popular than the separate games. As for your proposed solution, I disagree with having sonic 3 AND sonic-and-knuckles tags on questions - A question will relate to sonic-3 AND the combined game, but not sonic & knuckles (and vice-versa).

Comment: However, I'm now leaning toward my second proposed solution. You and @MatthewRead have convinced me off the first one.

Comment: @Robotnik I disagree that it's incorrect. According to Wikipedia, playing them together "This features several additions to the games not available otherwise, such as small alterations to the levels, and being able to play through Sonic 3 levels as Knuckles, or Sonic & Knuckles levels as Tails, and the ability to save progress in all of the game's levels." So it DOES modify Sonic 3. It's possible that someone may want to ask a question about the modifications to the base game, or the base game without the modifications. These tags should remain separate.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland - I'm agreeing with you that they should be separate tags now-  but I am saying that of the current questions, we should add the sonic-3-and-knuckles tag, as (gameplay wise) the questions are relating to the same things in game. If anything it will only help search results

Comment: @Robotnik Sorry, I originally misunderstood your second resolution. When you said "add [tag:sonic-3-and-knuckles] to all the questions in the other tags," I thought you meant all questions (present and future) should have it added, which I disagreed with. If you want to add it to the existing questions that it does relate to, I have no problems with that.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland - Ah, I see now, sorry for the confusion. I was trying to say that you'd be hard pressed to find a question in either game that doesn't relate to the combined game as well, and that we should add the combined tag where appropriate.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland - I've reworded my question to take that into account. Do you want to clear up your answer to better reflect our combined understanding?

Comment: @Robotnik Good call, updated.