# Is the same situation in two games too broad?

Tags: discussion, closing

Assuming that I ask for a solution in FIFA 18 and 19 and the controls are the same, thanks to classic controls, so the solution will work for both games.

Can this be too broad given the circumstances, that the controls are indeed equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is the same situation in two games too broad?*

**No.**

For example, this is pretty much what the [<gamename>-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-series) tags are for: questions that apply to multiple games in a series. The 'Too Broad' close reason states:

> #### Too Broad
>
> *Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once...*

There's nothing there restricting you from asking the same question, about the exact same situation in two games.

However, a question asker should generally **tag with the game they're playing** and let the *answers* state whether it applies to other games too. I think that's the only hard and fast rule that can be applied here, and there are always exceptions. Your hypothetical question about controls that applies to both FIFA-18 and FIFA-19 probably wont apply to *every* FIFA game ever made, and thus I'd say tagging with a broad [fifa-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-series) tag *wouldn't* make sense there. Another example is the [Sonic 3 & Knuckles situation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7451/28182), where two separate games can combine into one distinct game, so we have tags for all 3 and they are all applied as-needed.

So I see no problem with using two or more game tags *if the question and answer is the same on both* *, and it certainly doesn't make a question 'Too Broad'.

<sub>* Question askers generally won't know if an answer is the same on other games up-front, but it doesn't preclude the possibility of adding a tag as an edit later on should the answers apply to multiple games (or removing a tag should they not).</sub>

Comment: Another example, a question I self-answered about [Fallout 3 and Fallout New Vegas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129538/28182)

Comment: I've deleted the question again (probably too quickly, because I'm not always in the mood for endless discussions), but yes... I tried to ask something that occurred in FIFA 18 and 19  and tagged it accordingly with both games and it got bad feedback when I rollbacked an unwanted edit trying to remove one tag.

Comment: Questions should be tagged and judged solely on the question, not on their answers. I disagree with what you're saying, as I think it possible that a user might know the answer for one game, but not the other. When that happens, should they answer with just what they know? Then the answer is incomplete, as the question is asking for both. I don't think we should have cases like those. As long as it's plausible for the answers to be different and unrelated, as is the case with two different games, the questions should be asked separately.

Comment: ..and earn a dupe closure, which happens way too often here already. No, I still disagree with asking the same thing two times. It's more useful then to tag only one game and retag it later as some sort of consent.

Comment: @dly They wouldn't be closed. Questions about different games are not closed (even though some moderators think it's fine to answer a question about a game with information about a different game)

Comment: @dly I didn't realise you'd actually asked the question - I thought it was a hypothetical... sorry about that! @ Wrigglenite - tagging exists to sort and filter content appropriately - As I stated in the footnote: question askers generally shouldn't know if their question applies to two games - they're asking a question, unless they're self-answering how could they know? In any case, *asking about the same situation in two games is not  'Too Broad'*, which is what this meta question asks and this answer applies to.

Comment: @Robotnik So you do agree that the asker can't possibly know if the answer is the same. In that case, why should they ask two unrelated questions? The answers have no reason to be related, hence the question is too broad.

Comment: @Wrigglenite *"why should they ask two unrelated questions?"* I disagree that they are unrelated questions, in fact I disagree that they are separate questions: because by definition it is **one** question that applies to *multiple* games. And questions that apply to multiple games have not been deemed 'Too Broad' for the entire time we've had [series] tags, so why would it suddenly be too broad if the answer applies to multiple games? That makes no sense.

Comment: And let's say, hypothetically, that there were only two FIFA games ever created: FIFA 1 and FIFA 2. Both had nearly identical menus and control schemes. Would you say the question @dly asked was too broad, if it had instead been tagged with [fifa-series] in this scenario?

Comment: @Robotnik Questions that apply to a series as a whole do not apply to individual games in the series. They are usually lore questions, not questions about game mechanics and other implementations that can change between games. Series tags are completely unrelated to this situation, so the comparison to those questions is what makes no sense.

Comment: @Robotnik I disagree completely with the "one question that applies to multiple games" idea. Can I ask where to obtain the Master Ball with the [pokemon-series] tag? What would I even gain from such a question? What about different series with similar mechanics where the same question can apply? As the answer to a question *can't be guaranteed to be the same* across multiple games, tagging a question with multiple games just means that any answer must contain the solution for every game tagged. This excludes valid answers that only apply to a single game, and that's what makes it too broad.

Comment: @Wrigglenite [tag:pokemon-series] has many questions about game mechanics that are non-game specific. Maybe not the location of the Master Ball, *where the answer changes from game to game*, but [Whether Leech Seed is a Status Effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338060/)? Or [When the HP bar colours tick over?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/331464/). The latter of which you edited to remove the game tag rather than VTC'ing as 'Too Broad' btw. If you truly believe that all game mechanics should be about a singular game then your stance is inconsistently applied.

Comment: ...(cont) and you should raise a meta if you think that we should re-ask every question where the same answer could apply to many different games. This meta is about a 'Too Broad' vote. I've given my reasons why I think it's the wrong call, I'm not going to try any further to convince you when your mind is made up.

Comment: @Robotnik Voted to close now. Thanks.

Comment: @Wrigglenite /facepalm .. you can't be serious with these votes. You edited one of these half a year ago and back then it wasn't too broad? You even *made* it broader back then.

Comment: @dly You're very lovely.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Thanks, but it still doesn't explain why you removed a game specific tag to make a question a lot broader than before and now you're closing it as too broad. That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @dly Ah, you seem to think I edited the question's scope, while I just gave it a more appropriate tag. Since the question was already about every game in the series, the gen 2 tag was useless.

Comment: @Wrigglenite alright, sounds reasonable. The text still says Gold/Silver though.

Answer (score -2):

The post is asking two separate and unrelated questions: "How do you do X in Fifa 18?" and "How do you do X in Fifa 19?".

> The controls are the same, thanks to classic controls, so the solution will work for both games.

That's an assumption about the nature of the answer, which has no impact when judging whether a question is on-topic or not. It could be due to a setting in some menu. It could happen automatically under different circumstances in both games.
As it stands, the question could have two unrelated answers, which makes it too broad for a single post.

Comment: Yes, it is a setting in the menu - the *default* setting. I'm not asking where to find something I've previously changed, because that would make no sense, even with mentioning/tagging only one game. The answer for both would be based on the default settings for both, which is still identical. It looks only too broad for someone who doesn't know the games. I am asking this for both games, because it's the very same thing and the answer would be the solution for both games. I couldn't care less about the tagging myself, but if someone seeks help in 18 and it's only in 19 they may not find it.

Comment: You're still applying the same assumption - that the games have identical menus, settings, and controls. That is not part of the question, it is part of the answer. You can't know that the answers are the same without knowing what the answers are, and questions are judged solely on the question, not their answers.

Comment: They do, except for some newly added extras. And assuming no one who asks a question about them knows that is not helpful.

Comment: Well, I've said all that needs to be said. They're potentially unrelated questions, so they should be separate. If you don't like that, make a meta about using information from a question's answers to judge the question.