# Can I use more than one Minecraft tag if my question applies to more than one edition of Minecraft?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

Being an avid Minecraft player, I find myself playing on both the Java Edition and the Bedrock Edition of Minecraft. This also allows me to help out more people on a broader range.

Sometimes, even the experts get stuck, though, and I have to revert to asking on Arqade for help with a specific problem I am stuck on.

Most of my problems apply to both editions of Minecraft at once, as I build identical items on both editions. I am wondering, is it okay to use more than one of [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) and [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) at once on a question?

More specifically, should the tags you choose be:

- Only one edition, even if you are seeking answers to more than one edition.
- Only the edition(s) you are seeking answers to, even if the answer is the same in other editions that you are not using now.
- The editions that you are seeking answers to, as well as any editions that you *know* have the same answer to.

Comment: Related: [Is the same situation in two games too broad?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13128/28182)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to include unnecessary tags, even if an answer would apply to them. You're tagging the question, not the answers. **Don't use tags you're not seeking answers to**.

If you want an answer for multiple editions and **you are sure correct answers would apply to them all** it's safe to tag the question accordingly. In that case you could tag the question with the editions you are seeking answers to.

If you're **unsure** (maybe there are multiple approaches to solve your issue, but they work only with certain editions or versions) you should tag the question with only one edition (and ask a different question for the other edition).

Comment: What about if you’re actively seeking answers to multiple editions and know the answers will be different for sure?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 that's a perfect scenario for two (or more) separate questions.

Comment: "You are sure correct answers would apply to them all" doesn't mean being sure that the answers are the same, but that the answers *must* be the same, no matter what happens in either game. There are very few cases where that is true.

Comment: I know there are only a few cases, but in Minecraft it certainly is possible, as well as in some Source Engine games, FIFA, CoD, etc.

Comment: Say you create separate questions for each edition because you're unsure about the similarities, and then they turn out to be the same answer, with *no difference*, in all the editions. Is it then acceptable to merge them into one master question for that issue with both tags?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 that would be possible, yes. But this only makes sense if you want to retain and collect all the answers in one post. If there's still a slight possibility of difference with an additional answer (maybe the Java edition has some fancy commands) it's better to keep them separated.